# CollectionView ItemTemplate on removing and inserting

Tags: xamarin.forms, collectionview

When I insert a new match after removing one from the collection view.
It remembers the last match's state.

[here if I have selected Chelsea previously it will kept the 2nd option selected for the new entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPndI.png)

So I have CollectionItemView custom control defined and used in the collection view item template and the collection view is binded with an observable collection from which I remove the item upon removing item CollectionItemView disappears but when I insert new item in the observable collection the state of previously removed CollectionItemView restore itself.

Comment: How can we possibly help you if you don't show us what you are doing?  Please read [ask] before posting.

Comment: I have added more details

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Couldy you please post some code snippets or a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Answer (score 0):

Bind itemsource to an observablecollection and remove from/add to that. Any changes will impact the UI.